# Sort date a list of <a> tags that contain a date along with other non-date text?

Tags: javascript, string, date, sorting

This is the HTML containing a list of `<a>` tags containing the date within the `.caption2` class. By default the list of these episodes are NOT sorted by date. How can I sort them by date with oldest being on top of the list and latest at the end of the list?

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-5">
  <h2 class="separatorbar">All Episodes</h2>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+R7DU820ug">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/1174581"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          489: Very Inappropriate Thoughts About This Computer
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 30 • 114 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QCwmMHIhs">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/1051401"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          Priest and Joe Illidge on crafting new villain Entropy without any
          rules
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 26 • 87 min left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QwxKgVw_o">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/1098514"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Ep. 647: Best Sci Fi Beach Reading</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 27 • 27 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+HdT7S_15E">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/488766"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Filosofía de coyote</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 29 • 25 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this hard coded HTML? if not, sort BEFORE you generate it is the way to go. Either way, you'll need some sort of "code" to sort those elements ... also, without a year, the date you have is kind of meaningless

Comment: It is hardcoded. So I'm trying to figure out from my end to sort it.

Comment: You have two answers now - so, stop trying to figure it out yourself - the code is written for you below

Comment: I did stop trying to figure it out thanks to both answers. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's use the below functions:

[Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),
[Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector),
[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from),
[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort),
[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),
[Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore),
[HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText),
[Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement),
[Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse),
[String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split),
and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

**UPDATE:** Performance improvements

```js
// get date from element by inner text
const getDate = e => {
  return e.parsedDate ?? (e.parsedDate = Date.parse(`${e.querySelector(".caption2").innerText.split(/\s+•\s+/)[0]}, 2000`));
};

// find the a elements
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a.episodecell"))
// sort by date
  .sort((a, b) => getDate(b) - getDate(a))
// replace node position by reinserting
  .reduce((prev, cur) => cur.parentElement.insertBefore(cur, prev));
```

```html
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-5">
  <h2 class="separatorbar">All Episodes</h2>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+R7DU820ug">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/1174581"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          489: Very Inappropriate Thoughts About This Computer
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 30 • 114 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QCwmMHIhs">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/1051401"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          Priest and Joe Illidge on crafting new villain Entropy without any
          rules
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 26 • 87 min left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QwxKgVw_o">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/1098514"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Ep. 647: Best Sci Fi Beach Reading</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 27 • 27 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+HdT7S_15E">
    <img
      class="art"
      src="https://example.com/488766"
    />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Filosofía de coyote</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 29 • 25 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: All dates seem to be `NaN` in value - did you forget a year?

Comment: Oh, I see what you did ... you assumed all browsers work like Google Chrum ... sorry, but `Date.parse('Jun 26')` is `NaN` in a real browser

Comment: What is real browser?

Comment: Anything that is NOT Chrome - or based on Chromium drech

Comment: But my point is, your answer relies on a Chrum specific implementation of `Date.parse` - which won't work unless you use a Chrum based browser

Comment: Tested now on Edge and Firefox. Seems only Firefox returns NaN. Let me update my answer

Comment: Well, Edge is the Google PIG wearing Microsoft LIPSTICK ... if it works in Chrum it works in Edge - so, that's no surprise at all - I'd be tempted, when writing code, to test in Chrum, Firefox and the new Internet Explorer (Safari)

Comment: Please note, the ONLY specified string format to be guaranteed to work with Date.parse is *ISO 8601 format* ... anything else is implementation specific ... not sure who at google decided "a date without a year is fine"

Comment: @Bravo I still haven't understood that you do not consider Chrome like a real browser. For me it is real browser, since the team behind keeps it up-to-date as always. Could you please explain why?

Comment: @Bravo—ECMA-262 supports [3 formats for parsing](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse): its simplified version of ISO 8601 plus the formats produced by *Date.prototype.toString* and *toUTCString*. However, your point is valid: parsing of unsupported formats by the built–in parser should not be relied upon.

Comment: Relying on parsing of an unsupported format is not a good idea. Also, parsing a string to create another string that is then also parsed to create a Date is inherently inefficient. Just get the parts and give them to the Date constructor or Date.UTC.

Comment: @RobG - I went by MDN docs that says ONLY ISO 8601 is *specified* ... it's unusual that MDN get it wrong, but I guess Mozilla have more to worry about than being the de-facto go-to for documentation

Comment: @RobG meanwhile, while `new Date` creates a new Date object, `Date.parse` returns a number. Why would I need a `Date` obj? And the `Date.UTC` is calling the `parse` function internally. So, why would I use `Date.UTC` since it is already calling the same parse function? And also my implementation is faster. https://jsbench.me/53l550ofmp/1

Comment: All your questions are answered in my comment. To clarify: calling *new Date* with year, month and day arguments avoids calling *Date.parse* and parsing of unsupported formats. Parsing a string to create another string that is then parsed by the built–in parser is inefficient and, in this case, requires parsing of an unsupported format.  *Date.UTC* does not call *Date.parse*. Your tests all use parsing of an unsupported format, they don't test the speed of various methods of converting a timestamp in mmm d format to a time value which is what my comment addresses.

Comment: [This test](https://jsbench.me/kzl55913wx/1) that compares the speed of different approaches. A double parse is slower than a single parse plus either *Date.UTC* or *new Date* in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox (which highlights the problems with ECMAScript speed comparisons). Only the date conversion is tested in a context similar to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @bravo's approach of generating an array with date objects first and then sorting over it. Here is his version with a few light adjustments:

- I calculate the target.element `cont` only once
- instead of `.insertAdjacentElement()` I use the simpler `append()`

```js
const cont=document.querySelector(".pure-u-1");
[...document.querySelectorAll(".episodecell")]
 .map(a=>({a,date:new Date(a.querySelector(".caption2").textContent.split("•")[0]+"1972")}))
 .sort((a,b)=>a.date-b.date)
 .forEach(a=>cont.append(a.a))
```

```html
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-5">
  <h2 class="separatorbar">All Episodes</h2>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+R7DU820ug">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/1174581" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          489: Very Inappropriate Thoughts About This Computer
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 30 • 114 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QCwmMHIhs">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/1051401" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          Priest and Joe Illidge on crafting new villain Entropy without any rules
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 26 • 87 min left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QwxKgVw_o">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/1098514" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Ep. 647: Best Sci Fi Beach Reading</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 27 • 27 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+HdT7S_15E">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/488766" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Filosofía de coyote</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 29 • 25 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree - this is neater ...

Comment: https://jsbench.me/53l550ofmp/1 does not affect the speed. How would it help to performance?

Comment: I did not claim that the performance was better. As long as you have a manageable number of dates being displayed on the page (i. e. something in the order of <1000) the time spent in sorting and rearranging should be small enough to not play a major role. My intention was to make the code a little easier to read and maintain. But in the end it is a matter of personal preference, which style you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML you posted is generated from some API, it's best to sort the data, then create the HTML

However, to sort the `<a>` in the existing HTML, you can do as follows

Note, since there is no year value for any date, I chose 1972 ... doesn't matter which year you use though, but pick a leap year so `Feb 29` is valid

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".episodecell")].map(a=>({a,date:new Date(a.querySelector(".caption2").textContent.split("•")[0]+"1972")})).sort(({date:a},{date:b})=>b-a).forEach(({a})=>document.querySelector("h2.separatorbar").insertAdjacentElement('afterend',a))
```

```html
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-5">
  <h2 class="separatorbar">All Episodes</h2>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+R7DU820ug">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/1174581" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          489: Very Inappropriate Thoughts About This Computer
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 30 • 114 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QCwmMHIhs">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/1051401" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">
          Priest and Joe Illidge on crafting new villain Entropy without any rules
        </div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 26 • 87 min left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+QwxKgVw_o">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/1098514" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Ep. 647: Best Sci Fi Beach Reading</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 27 • 27 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="episodecell" href="/+HdT7S_15E">
    <img class="art" src="https://example.com/488766" />
    <div class="cellcontent">
      <div class="titlestack">
        <div class="title singleline">Filosofía de coyote</div>
        <div class="caption2 singleline">Jun 29 • 25 min</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```